# confusion regarding mid level image processing task?

Tags: image-processing

I am reading gonzalez chapter1 As shown highlighted in attached snapshot, what is meant by this mid level task: **description of those objects to reduce them to a form suitable for computer processing,**

please kindly elaborate/explain this statement,preferably with example

[image]

Comment: Is there something specific that you do not get from this passage? Are you looking for specific examples?

Answer (score 1):

Extracting and classifying information in an image is termed as mid level task. We are basically detecting, classifying features (for example, high motion, slow motion/movement in an image) or classifying objects (like fingertips, see figure below) On the left you see finger tips classified with their positions,

Here, we are "extracting" the contour of the hand and then based on the shape of contour near a finger tip we are "classifying" that as a fingertip.

[image]

or contour detection, to identify objects, such as banana in the example below. Now these processed grey scale or binary images can  be suitably used for fast calculations in a computer

[image]

Hope that clear the doubt

Comment: Very Nice graphics demonstration. But in  your fingertips example, what are extracting and classifying steps?please kindly elaborate,both parts/steps of your example separately?

Comment: @engr sure, have added the statement in the answer